# Creation of singleton instance in +load

Tags: objective-c, singleton, objective-c-runtime

Everyone have seen or used code like this to create singleton instance:

```
static MySingletonClass *instance;

+(MySingletonClass*)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [self new];
    });

    return instance;
}
```

I'm wondering: why not just use +load method, which is called once for statically loaded classes? This would allow us to omit check for instance existence:

```
static MySingletonClass *instance;

+(void)load
{
    instance = [self new];
}
```

Assume that -init doesn't depend on another classes' +load methods to be called (as it should be). What can go wrong? Which disadvantages or hidden dangers are there?

Comment: Could you do add `NSLog(@"Instance pointer: %p", instance);` after you `[self new]` abd call `+load` twice and see the difference?

Comment: No need to do that to say that log will show two different values, but what does it mean? Also no need to do that, because `+(void)load` method isn't called directly and for statically loaded classes is called only once by classes loader.

Comment: Unnecessary resources. `+load` is called at the time your binary is loaded, why create an instance of a class if it's never used by the rest of the program? It's cheaper to allocate the dispace_once_t in the .data section (which is just an int32 which is atomically swapped 2 or 3 times as a cheap spinlock) than to do a heap allocation at the point of binary load.